# How to properly use a c++ static library (.lib) in a Android shared library (.so) project in Visual Studio?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I need to create a .so Android shared library for a project, and I need to use functions from a C++ static library (.lib). The .so library is meant to be used just as a bridge, so I can use functions from my static library in Android apps and games. I've created a C++ cross-platform Android project in Visual Studio 2017 (also testing it in VS2019), included the header file for the static library and the library itself, and everything is theoretically configured and linked.

The current library I'm using is a simple static library for tests that has just a single function:

```
namespace StaticLibrary
{
    extern "C" void Func() 
    {
        // something
    }
}
```

The file for the Android looks something like this:

```
#include "StaticLibraryHeader.h"
extern "C"
{
    // ...

    void StaticLibFunc()
    {
        StaticLibrary::Func();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the project, the compiler says:

```
C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: F:\Android_IOS_libs\MobileLibraries2019\Build\x64\Debug\libStaticLibTest_x64_Debug.lib: bad extended name index at 778
```

and:

```
undefined reference to 'Func'
```

I can get rid of this second error by using the --whole-archive option of the linker but then this new error shows up, along with the first one:

```
C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: fatal error: F:\Android_IOS_libs\MobileLibraries2019\Build\x64\Debug\libStaticLibTest_x64_Debug.lib: attempt to map 60 bytes at offset 6324 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
```

I've also used Google Lib2A ( https://code.google.com/archive/p/lib2a/ ) to create a .a file, but then the following error happens:

```
C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: F:\Android_IOS_libs\MobileLibraries2019\Krilloud_Android\lib\x64\libStaticLibTestDLL_x64_Debug.a: member at 192 is not an ELF object
C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: F:\Android_IOS_libs\MobileLibraries2019\Krilloud_Android\lib\x64\libStaticLibTestDLL_x64_Debug.a: member at 870 is not an ELF object
C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: F:\Android_IOS_libs\MobileLibraries2019\Krilloud_Android\lib\x64\libStaticLibTestDLL_x64_Debug.a: member at 1656 is not an ELF object
```

I'm not an Android/Java developer, so I'm lost here. How do I properly link and use my static library in a .so project? Can it be done using Visual Studio or do I really need to install Android Studio for this? I will also need to create the same thing for iOS, so I was hoping to have both projects in a Visual Studio solution.

Comment: You need to make your static library with the Android tool-chain

Comment: @RichardCritten how do I do that?